# Comparison arrow object between two bar containers

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have the following two arrays:

```
base = np.arange(2)

y_axis = [32.59, 28.096]
```

And the following code

```
base = np.arange(2)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(15)

bars = ax.bar(base, y_axis, width = 0.3)
bars[0].set_color('g')
ax.bar_label(bars,[f'{i}%' for i in y_axis])
ax.set_xticks(base, labels = ['Simplificado','Não simplificados'])
ax.arrow(base[0],y5,dx = base[1], dy = x5-y5)
```

[image: Resulting image]

That results in the following image

What I want to do is a comparison, arrow something kinda like this. Any ideas on a way to build up such arrow?

Sorry for bad image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`matplotlib.path`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html).
That can be used to draw polygons or also just a polyline following a specific path as used for this case.

This plot isn't optimized to look pretty (see notes at the end for potential improvement), but to show the concept:

[image]

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath

base = np.arange(2)
y_axis = [32.59, 28.096]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(15)

path_y_gap = 5
delta_value = y_axis[1] - y_axis[0]

Path = mpath.Path
path_data = [
    (Path.MOVETO, (base[0],y_axis[0])),
    (Path.MOVETO, (base[0],y_axis[0]+path_y_gap)),
    (Path.MOVETO, (base[1],y_axis[0]+path_y_gap)),
    #(Path.MOVETO, (base[1],y_axis[1])),  # alternative to the arrow
    ]
codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
x, y = zip(*path.vertices)
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'k-')

ax.text( 0.5 , y_axis[0] + path_y_gap + 0.5, round(delta_value,2))


ax.arrow(base[1], y_axis[0]+path_y_gap, 0, -(-delta_value + path_y_gap),
         head_width = 0.02 , head_length = 0.8, length_includes_head =  True)

bars = ax.bar(base, y_axis, width = 0.3)
bars[0].set_color('g')
ax.bar_label(bars,[f'{i}%' for i in y_axis])
ax.set_xticks(base, labels = ['Simplificado','Não simplificados'])
```

**Notes:**

- `path` doesn't offer arrow shaped ends, as a workaround the last section is done by a normal matplotlib `arrow`

  - Check the alternative in the `path_data` to the arrow for the last section
- I haven't dealt with overlay of the bar % text and the path / arrow, but you could e.g. easily put a y-offset variable to start/end above that text
- Check Bézier example in the [matplotlib path tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html) if you prefer a 'rounded' line
- You may for sure adapt the float digits another way than the used `round()`
- The first `MOVETO` sets the starting point, an explicit endpoint isn't required.

Comment: Oh man if i could upvote you twice i would